# Convert time don't work on a column's dataframe

Tags: r, datetime, sapply, iso8601

I have some data from event producer. In a "created_at column I have mixed type of datetime value.

Some NA, some ISO8601 like, some POSIX with and without millisec.

I build a func that should take care of everything meanning let's NA and ISO8601 info as it is, and convert POSIX date to ISO8601.

```r
library(anytime)
convert_time <- function(x) {
  nb_char = nchar(x)
  if (is.na(x)) return(x)
  else if (nb_char == 10 | nb_char == 13) {
    num_x = as.numeric(x)
    if (nb_char == 13) {
      num_x = round(num_x / 1000, 0)
    }
    return(anytime(num_x))
  }
  return(x)
}
```

If I passe one problematic value
`convert_time("1613488656")`

> "2021-02-16 15:17:36 UTC"

Works well !

Now

```
df_offer2$created_at = df_offer2$created_at %>% sapply(convert_time)
```

I still have the problematic values.

Any tips here ?

Comment: everything looks ok imo. could you post some of your dataframe df_offer2 that reproduces your problem?

Comment: The problem is that `sapply` removes the date format from the output of `convert_time`. Also, a dataframe cannot have a column of mixed types, so your input is probably all character, and your output might also be coerced to all character. We might need a more representative sample of your mixed data to find a robust solution to this.

Comment: @AndrewGustar You are right I forget to add that everything at first is char, but at the end I write the DF into a postregre table with a timestamp type column, so it convert the char ISO8691 type correctly keeping the NA where it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following small changes...

```
convert_time <- function(x) {
  nb_char = nchar(x)
  if (is.na(x)) return(x)
  else if (nb_char == 10 | nb_char == 13) {
    num_x = as.numeric(x)
    if (nb_char == 13) {
      num_x = round(num_x / 1000, 0)
    }
    return(num_x)                        #remove anytime from here
  }
  return(x)
}

df_offer2$created_at = df_offer2$created_at %>% 
    sapply(convert_time) %>% anytime()   #put it back in at this point
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things that have worked for me:

```
col1<-seq(from=1,to=10)
col2<-rep("1613488656",10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(col1,col2))
colnames(df)<-c("index","created_at")


df <- df%>%
  mutate(converted = convert_time(df$created_at))`
```

alternatively

```
col1<-seq(from=1,to=10)
col2<-rep("1613488656",10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(col1,col2))
colnames(df)<-c("index","created_at")


df$created_at <- convert_time(df$created_at)
```

Both spit out warnings but appear to make the correction properly